# Opera Browser: highlight the URL bar

Tags: opera, url

In Opera Browser what is the key combination to highlight the url bar?

I tried the F6 key, but doesn't work.

I'm using Opera 23, latest build.

Comment: I believe it's `F2`

Comment: Doesn't work for me.

Comment: Are you using a notebook computer? If it has a `Fn` key, you might have to press `Fn` + `F2`

Comment: It's a desktop computer, but keyboard has Fn key. Tried Fn + F2 and doesn't work.

Comment: Okay, my bad. It's `F8`. Source: http://www.opera.com/help/tutorials/nomouse/#essential

Comment: @Vinayak Have in mind that most/all Opera help pages are outdated since they are for Opera 12.17 (old Presto). But luckily `F8` has still the same function

Comment: Yes! F8 works. Also discovered CONTROL+L combination.

Answer (score 3):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>

Works in pretty much all browsers on all operating systems. Even in Internet Explorer in Metro mode and Chrome Mobile with a keyboard attached.

Comment: Nope. :( Opera 56.0.3051.43, macos 10.13.6. Nope. Not even F8 as they say in the guide.